# Can you re-enter as a visitor with time left on a working visa?

Tags: canada

Can you re-enter as a visitor with time left on a working visa? Does anyone have experience of this?

To give my own example, I'm planning to do this soon, with a working holiday visa that expires in about 3 weeks. My hope is that if they're not willing to let me in as a visitor I can come in on the work visa. (I'll of course mention it if they start asking questions relevant to it.)

Comment: This could depend on the country... But generally, as long as your visa is valid, you're free to enter the country.